# How to get slow query on PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12, postgresql-13, postgresql-14

Basically I want to log those query which is taking more than 300ms to execute. I don't want to log those query which is less than 300ms. But at PostgreSQL showing all type of log whether it is below 300ms or above 300ms.

I configured below parameter:

- log_directory = 'pg_log'
- log_filename = 'postgresql-%a.log'
- log_statement = 'all'
- logging_collector = on
- log_min_duration_statement = 300

Why PostgreSQL log all type of statement, though I set parameter log_min_duration_statement=300?
It is confusing to me, Is there any better configuration to log only 300ms SQL statement?

Comment: "log_statement = 'all'" will log all statements.  Turn that off if you don't want that to happen.

Comment: Yes I have tried with others but issue is that I want all statement which is above 300ms whatever it is? Then how I can do it?

Comment: What specifically happened (or didn't happen) when you tried turning "log_statement = 'none'" while keeping you other settings?  Provide concrete examples.  Just saying that it is not what you want doesn't tell us anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`log_statement` being set to `all` is telling PostgreSQL to log the text of all statements.  When used together with `log_min_duration_statement`, statement text is not repeated in logs, forcing manual correlations by process/session identifier for analysis.  If you truly want `log_statement` set to `all` (you want the text of all statements to be logged), be sure to be logging the process and/or session identifier (see `log_line_prefix` and its `%p` and `%c` "escape sequences").  Otherwise, consider setting `log_statement` to `none`.  *Note that `log_duration` will also lead to logging for all statements.*

On a loosely related note, consider checking out `pg_stat_statements`, a PostgreSQL-supplied module, function, and view that provides planning and execution statistics for executed queries.  This module has proven itself very useful in the past.  If interested, check out [PostgreSQL: pg_stat_statements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgstatstatements.html).